# Asymptotics of a function

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

I hope this question is not too simple, but I would like to know the asymptotic behaviour of the following function $f: \mathbb{N}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ where
$$
f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^n}{n^{4i}}
$$
Any references, pointers, or answers would be most appreciated.

Comment: $f(n)=n^{n+o(n)}$.

Comment: Thanks Didier - that certainly agrees with the data. Would you mind briefly sketching your reasoning?

Comment: Which context did you meet this beast in?

Comment: It popped up in the analysis of an algorithm. According to Maple the corresponding integral can be expressed in terms of a Whittaker function.

Comment: You should be able to get this with the Laplace method for sums - find the dominant term, convert the Riemann sum to an integral of the form $\int dx \exp(f(x-x_0)) $ and use Laplace's method to estimate the integral. See Bender and Orszag's book for an example.

Comment: If one wants a crude asymptotic like the one Didier suggests, finding the dominant term for the lower bound and giving the obvious upper bound is sufficient. In any case, all ingredients are given in various comments, so either one cook up an answer that Granger will be able to accept, or we close as « off topic » (if the question is considered too simple) or « non longer relevant », but there is no need letting it popping up.

Comment: @Granger: Just to add to the comments and responses so far, the terms increase up to $i\approx n/(4\log n)$, then they decrease indefinitely, hence the difference of the sum and the analogous integral is at most twice the maximum of the integrand. Now the maximum of the integrand is about $n^{-1/2}$ times the integral, hence indeed we get an asymptotic formula.

Comment: I summarized the comments in a short answer, in the hope we can close this topic.

Comment: @Granger: I updated the asymptotic formula, as it was not quite correct. See Brendan McKay's comment to my response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments so far (including mine above) it follows that
$$ f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^n}{n^{4i}}=\frac{n!}{(4\ln n)^{n+1}}\left(1+O(n^{-1/2}\ln n)\right). $$

Comment: and by Stirling's formula this gives us $f(n)=\sqrt{2 \pi n} (\frac{n}{4e \ln n})^n  (1+O(n^{-1/2}))$.

Comment: @Johan: Yes. In fact the error term I indicated comes from Stirling's formula. Either way, you have to compare $(n/e)^n$ with $n!$.

Comment: @Johan: Note that for you version we need the refined Stirling's formula with explicit error term.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the power of $4\ln n$ should be $n+1$ and not $n$.

Comment: And the error term is exponentially small.  The Euler-Maclaurin formula will show it.

Comment: @Brendan: You are right about $n+1$ vs. $n$, I will fix this. Regarding a better error term, I am not so sure, and it is not needed for the original problem.

Comment: Experimentally the error falls exponentially, but proving it might not be so easy.  The individual terms in the E-M expansion fall rapidly, but the error term is trickier.  I'll stop working on it now.

Answer (score -1):

$f(n) = n^n 4^{-4n} (1 + O(n^{-4}))$.  The sum is strongly dominated by its last term.  I hope this isn't homework.

**Apologies**.  I misread the question exact as Benoît suggests.

Comment: Didn't you took a $n$ for a $4$? The last term is $n^{-3n}$.

Comment: The last term is $n^{-3n}$, which is certainly not dominant! The asymptotics is probably obtainable by comparing with
$$\int_0^\infty x^n n^{-4x}\,dx=\frac{n!}{(4\ln n)^n}.$$

Comment: The main contribution is around $i=n/(4\log n)$, not around $i=n$.

Comment: @Michael: I think your observation will do nicely (having bounded the contribution of the tail $x > n$). Thanks!